# Quick simple question about Python Keyboard input coding

Tags: python

python amateur here.

Coding in Python 3.x, and i'm trying to allow keyboard input

```
        if keyinput == "right": #D 0x20
            PressKey(D)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            ReleaseKey(D)
            time.sleep(0.2);
```

How do I code so that whenever keyinput is "right #" (given any number of seconds), then the time.sleep(#) is the given #?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: if  `"right #"` is a string then split it and convert second element to `int` - `int("right 7".spit(" ")[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go:

```
interval = int(input.split(" ")[1])
time.sleep(interval)
```

split will split based on delimiter as space and 1 index (0 indexed) will contain the interval to sleep.